# Replace character sequence in a string without whitespaces - java

Tags: java, string, replace

I am trying to replace the character sequence "&a" with ""

So I can have for example: "This&aIs&aA&aTest" -> "ThisIsATest"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [String#replace](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence%29).

```
String yourString = "This&aIs&aA&aTest";
yourString = yourString.replace("&a", "");
```

Answer (score 3):

Using `String.replace`:

```
s = s.replace("&a", "");
```

Remember that strings are immutable. `String.replace` doesn't actually modify the string. You need to assign the result back to the variable.

See it working online: [ideone](http://ideone.com/oQYdc)

Answer (score 1):

Use a regular expression with the replaceAll()

```
str.replaceAll("&a", "");
```

Answer (score -4):

This is exactly what the String object's replace function is for. If you want to get all occurrences of the &a, use a Regular expression, like so:

```
<html>
<script>

a =  "This&aIs&aA&aTest"

alert(a.replace(new RegExp ("&a", "g") , " "));

</script>
</html>
```

or replaceAll().

Comment: OP is using Java, not Javascript.

Comment: Oops. That it is. 3rd day on this site. Sowwy

Comment: you can always delete your answer and gain reputation back :)